# Verilog Code:FIR Filter= RAM modeling for reading coefficients values from file .. not showing simulation results

Tags: filter, verilog, ram, coefficients

In verilog for only this line of code its showing simulation output

1)

```
#( parameter width=1, length=16 )
       (* ram_style = "block" *)
          reg [(width)-1:0] mem[(1<<length)-1:0];
```

2)but for the below line it is not showing simulation output

```
  #( parameter width=8, length=16 )
   (* ram_style = "block" *)
         reg [(2*width)-1:0] mem[(1<<length)-1:0];
```

Explain why 2nd set of code is not showing simulation results?
actually I want store 8 bits of min 65535 filter coefficients.. I want to read and write .. 
please guide me in this...

Comment: for width and depth of memory it is more common to do: `reg [(width-1):0] mem [0:(depth-1)];`

Comment: ya but i want depth of 65535 and 8 bits wide .. So how to code?

Comment: `reg [(8-1):0] mem [0:(65535-1)];` replacing width and depth with the values you specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A model of a RAM might look some thing like the code below, to write to it it is just a mater of sequencing the wr_addr, wr_data and wr_en.

```
module ram #(
  parameter DATA_W = 8,
  parameter DATA_D = 256
) (
  input                      clk,
  input                     rst_an,
  input  [0:$clog2(DATA_D)] rd_addr,
  input  [0:$clog2(DATA_D)] wr_addr,
  input  [0:DATA_W-1]       wr_data,
  input                     wr_en,
  output [0:DATA_W-1]       rd_data
);

reg [0:DATA_W-1] ram_data [0:DATA_D-1];

//READ
always @* begin
  rd_data = ram_data[rd_addr];
end

//WRITE
always @(posedge clk, negedge rst_an) begin
  if (~rst_an) begin
    for(int i = 0; i<DATA_D ; i++) begin
      ram_data[i]     <= 'b0 ;
    end 
  end
  else begin
    if (wr_en) begin
      ram_data[wr_addr] <= wr_data ;
    end
  end
end
```

`for(int i = 0; i<DATA_D ; i++)` is system verilog syntax.

for plain verilog declare `integer i` then replace the for loop with :

```
for(i = 0; i<DATA_D ; i=1+1)
```

clog2 : is used to get the address width required for the given depth.

If you want a depth of 4, you need 2 bits to address it. Depth of 16, 4 bits to address, ie

```
log2( 4) => 2
log2(16) => 4
```

If you use non-powers of two you want to round up or **ceiling**

```
log2(5)  => 2.32192809489
clog2(5) => 3
```

Therefore clog2 is very useful to get the required addressing width from the depth of the RAM.

Comment: Is `$clog2` supported in verilog too?

Comment: no but you can add it in as a function, should be on the internet some where ... [Xilinx](http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/44586.html)

Comment: why $clog2 it is used?

Comment: @SugureshKumarArali If you want a depth of 4, you need 2 bits to address it. depth of 16, 4 bits to address. `log2(4) => 2`, `log2(16) = > 4` if you use non-powers of two you want to round up or **ceiling** `log2(5) => 2.32192809489` compared with `clog2(5) => 3`.